# Python script to read a file and print if or not line of interest is present

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a simple python script to read through lines in different files that do not startswith "#" and print it. And if there is no line without "#" then should print as "No lines". Between each lines there is no empty lines.

File1:

```
#Name
Raphl
#last
```

file2:

```
#Name
#last
```

I would like to print lines that do have lines starting with '#'

```
f=['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']
l=[]
for files in f:
    f1=open(files, 'r')
    for lines in f1:
        
        if not lines.startswith('#'):
            l.append(lines)
            if len(l)>0:
                print ("file name:",files)
                print ("Interested line:",lines)
            if len(l)==0:
                print ("file name with empty lines:",'No lines')
```

For file1 it prints `Raphl` but for file2 it does not print `No lines`.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the first file is read, your code appends a line to `l`. Then, when reading the second file, `l` already has a length of 1.

To fix this, you need to define `l` each time a file is read.

> Update: Also, you need to wait for the program to loop through all lines. You can do this my changing the indentation on the if statement. I've updated the program and it should work now.

```py
f=['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']

for files in f:
    f1=open(files, 'r')
    l=[] # Each time a file is read, `l` is reset to an empty list
    for line in f1:
        
        if not line.startswith('#'):
            l.append(line)
            if len(l)>0:
                print ("file name:",files)
                print ("Interested line:",line)
    if len(l)==0:
        print ("file name with empty lines:",'No lines')
```

Comment: Thank you. But that did not solve the problem. Running the script it is still not printing if the len==0.

Comment: Sorry, I missed another issue with the code, but I've updated my answer now and it should work.